# Umbraco - No template exists to render the document

Tags: umbraco

I want to customize this error:

```
Page not found

No template exists to render the document at url 'someurl'.

This page is intentionally left ugly ;-)
```

I did edited `umbracosettings.config` :

```
<errors>
  <error404>4568</error404>
</errors>
```

But for some reason the custom 404 works with some pages and doesn't work with others.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure the visited page HAS a template in the "properties" tab?
Same question for the page with ID 4568: has it a template in the properties tab?

Comment: Which IIS server and umbraco version do you use?